# can't read SRT File

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, subtitle, srt

I have subtitle files in my raw folder, for LTR file I can read it properly( english subtitle for example), but for RTL file (like arabic subtitle) I can't read it and when I open it on android studio this is what I get :

```
2
00:00:06,478 --> 00:00:07,405
:�� ����� ����
������ �������� ����

3
00:00:07,407 --> 00:00:08,289
:� ����� �� ����� ����
���� �����
```

any help please, thank you.

Comment: this question does not belong here and this is why it has not been answered after all this time.